# Как совершить рендер страницы используя koa?

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Точного описание ни где не нашел, примерно попробовал много чего, остановился вот на этом примере

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
Router = require('koa-router'),
serve = require('koa-static'),
logger = require('koa-logger'),
views = require('koa-views'),
app = new Koa(),
router = new Router();

app.use(logger());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(router.routes());

app.use(views(__dirname + 'public/views', {extension: 'pug'}));

router.get('/', (ctx) => {
    ctx.render('index.pug', {title: 'Авторизация'})
});
```

И в ответ я получаю  ctx.render is not a function.
то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Koa = require('koa'),
    Router = require('koa-router'),
    router = new Router(),
    views = require('koa-views'),
    serve = require('koa-static'),
    bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser'),
    app = new Koa();
    
    const 
    
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {extension: 'pug'}));

router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
        auth(ctx);
        await ctx.render('login', {title: 'Авторизация'});
    })

app.use(router.routes());
```